# Error while creating a pod using kubernetes client API

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm trying to create a pod using Kubernetes client api in Go and I've been getting below error in TravisCI,

```
ERRO Running error: buildir: analysis skipped: errors in package: [/home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/pravarag/test-repo/check_pod.go:25:70: cannot use desiredPod (variable of type *"k8s.io/api/core/v1".Pod) as context.Context value in argument to s.kubeClient.CoreV1().Pods(desiredPod.Namespace).Create: missing method Deadline /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/pravarag/test-repo/check_pod.go:25:80: too few arguments in call to s.kubeClient.CoreV1().Pods(desiredPod.Namespace).Create
```

Below is the code,

```golang
import (
    "fmt"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
    core "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

func (s *server) createPod() {
    // build the pod definition
    desiredPod := getPodObjet()

    pod, err := s.kubeClient.CoreV1().Pods(desiredPod.Namespace).Create(desiredPod)
    if err != nil {
        s.log.Fatal("Failed to create the static pod", zap.Error(err))
    }
    fmt.Println("Created Pod: ", pod.Name)
}

func getPodObjet() *core.Pod {
    pod := &core.Pod{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name:      "test-pod",
            Namespace: "default",
            Labels: map[string]string{
                "app": "test-pod",
            },
        },
        Spec: core.PodSpec{
            Containers: []core.Container{
                {
                    Name:            "busybox",
                    Image:           "busybox",
                    ImagePullPolicy: core.PullIfNotPresent,
                    Command: []string{
                        "sleep",
                        "3600",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
    return pod
}
```

I tried to check what that error is pointing to and it seems, the actual pod Interface in K8s client code here: `https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/typed/core/v1#PodInterface`
is expecting 3 arguments: one is `"context.Context"`, `"pod *v1.Pod"` and `"opts metav1.CreateOptions"`
I tried to pass the values as:

```
pod, err :=s.kubeClient.CoreV1().Pods(desiredPod.Namespace).Create(context.Context, desiredPod, opts metav1.CreateOptions{})
```

But that doesn't work also. Even in the IDE, the code lint is pointing to missing arguments but I've seen couple of examples used to create a pod in above mentioned way that worked previously.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, and you seem to have explained it properly. `Create()` expects three arguments, but you're only passing one.

Comment: "But that doesn't work also" -- How does it not work? No doubt you get some other error message. What message do you get?

Comment: Note that `context.Context` is a _type_... you can't pass that directly to a function. You need a value of that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `context.TODO()` as argument to pass context.

try this one.

```
pod, err := s.kubeClient.CoreV1().Pods(desiredPod.Namespace).Create( context.TODO(), desiredPod , metav1.CreateOptions{})
```

here is the updated code:

```
import (
    "fmt"

    "context"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
    core "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

func (s *server) createPod() {
    // build the pod definition
    desiredPod := getPodObjet()

    pod, err := s.kubeClient.CoreV1().Pods(desiredPod.Namespace).Create( context.TODO(), desiredPod , metav1.CreateOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        s.log.Fatal("Failed to create the static pod", zap.Error(err))
    }
    fmt.Println("Created Pod: ", pod.Name)
}

func getPodObjet() *core.Pod {
    pod := &core.Pod{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name:      "test-pod",
            Namespace: "default",
            Labels: map[string]string{
                "app": "test-pod",
            },
        },
        Spec: core.PodSpec{
            Containers: []core.Container{
                {
                    Name:            "busybox",
                    Image:           "busybox",
                    ImagePullPolicy: core.PullIfNotPresent,
                    Command: []string{
                        "sleep",
                        "3600",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
    return pod
}
```

Comment: Thanks this one worked but one question here, why does it take an empty context and empty metav1.CreateOptions()

Comment: here is when we use context.TODO()
`TODO returns a non-nil, empty Context. Code should use context.TODO when it's unclear which Context to use or it is not yet available (because the
surrounding function has not yet been extended to accept a Context parameter).`

Comment: `metav1.CreateOptions{}` this one is used to pass extra info that will be needed in the creation step. but we don't need  any here.  so we just used an empty one